# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Digits' of undefined in twilio when gathering user input from call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have used the code from [Gather User Input via Keypad (DTMF Tones) in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-node-js) twilio documentation
for getting user input from the call.

```
    app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
       const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

       function gather() {
         const gatherNode = twiml.gather({ numDigits: 1 });
         gatherNode.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.');
         twiml.redirect('/voice');
       }
       if (request.body.Digits) {
         switch (request.body.Digits) {
         case '1':
           twiml.say('You selected sales. Good for you!');
           break;
         case '2':
           twiml.say('You need support. We will help!');
           break;
         default:
           twiml.say("Sorry, I don't understand that choice.").pause();
           gather();
           break;
        }
      } else {
    gather();
   }

  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
  });
```

When i call to my twilio number i'm getting error like "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'Digits' of undefined**" at the **if** statement.I want to get what number user enters during the call.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.It works fine now.The problem was in my service provider calling to the twilio number. I changed my service now works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your initial `request` have no `body` propery.
Try added a check to your `if` statement:

```
if (request.body && request.body.Digits) {
  // switch / case
} else {
  gather();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Log the value of request and inspect those properties,
 Comment out everything below: `if(request.body.Digits)`

And then run this in its place:

```
console.log(request)
```

Because the error is telling you that body isn't defined in that object.
Otherwise if it is there the incapsulate the switch statement in this

```
if(request.body)
{
//Switch statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue. Adding these two lines fixed it for me:

```
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

They were in the Twilio documentation as well. I'm a bit of a newbie at Node, so I'm not sure why the code breaks without them. According to the comment Twilio provided,
`// Parse incoming POST params with Express middleware`